# C#: Bouncy Castle PGP sign and encrypt in one pass

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

I need to sign and encrypt a file in one pass using C#. I have messed around with Bouncy Castle as well as PGPCore but I can't seem to get it to work.

Does anyone have an example of how to do it? I have a public key for encryption.